# WordPress group taxonomies for posts based on acf relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two posts types: `Teachers` and `Students`. The sample data:

Teachers Posts Type:

```
Teacher A
Teacher B
Teacher C
```

and the students post type:

```
Student A
Student B
Student C
and many more students
```

I also have a taxonomy called `student-role` which has some values:

```
Intern
Master Student
PhD Student
```

In the student post type, I am using an ACF relationship to assign a teacher to a student. A student can have more than one teacher.

For example:

- `Student A` is an `Intern` and is assigned to `Teacher A` and
  `Teacher B`
- `Student B` is a `Master Student` and is assigned to
  `Teacher C`
- `Student C` is a `PhD Student` and is assigned to `Teacher C`

I want to create a custom page for `teacher C` where I only show all `student-role`s.

So there is a page for Teacher C and it should list `Master Student` and `PhD Student` since there are two students under that taxonomy.

I tried to get all the students first, then all the student roles but not sure about what to do next, any ideas?

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'  => 'students',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'acf_relationship',
            'value'   => 'Manual ID OF Teacher',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
// get all posts for teacher with ID
$all_posts = get_posts( $args );

// get all student roles
$tax_terms = get_terms( 'student-role');
```

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you right now, I'd be leery about using a `meta_query` for this if you're using this at scale. A few hundred students and teachers won't be bad, but meta_queries can be painfully slow on large data sets because the `meta_value` field isn't indexed in the database

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom page named single-teacher.php?

1. First, you need to create single-teacher.php where you will display the teacher's page.
2. Inside the teacher's page you need to get student's object using ACF relation.
3. You will have the student's ID inside that object. Then, you can get its taxonomy easily.

Check this code.

```
<?php
// the get_the_ID() will get the teacher's ID since you are in single-teacher.php
// $the_post will be the student object

// $the_posts is the student's object
$the_posts = get_field('acf_relationship', get_the_ID()); 

if( $the_posts ): ?>
 <ul>
   <?php foreach( $the_posts as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post ?>
    <li>
        <!-- This will display the student title or name -->
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 
           $p->ID ); ?></a> 

        <!-- This will display the student's taxononmy -->
        <?php
        $the_terms = get_the_terms( $p->ID, 'your_taxonomy_name' );
        $t_url = '';
        $t_name = '';
        foreach ($the_terms as $t) {
            $t_url = get_term_link( $t->slug, 'your_taxonomy_name');
            $t_name = $t->name;
        }
        ?>
        <!-- Print student role list with link -->
        <span>Your student roles: <a href="<?php echo $t_url; ?>">
           <?php echo $t_name; ?></a>
        </span>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : ACF field assign for student should return only Post id not post object ( you can set by edit acf field )

Here Query for Teacher C ( post id of teacher c = 1662 )

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'student',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        if( in_array('1662', get_field('assign')) ) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">                
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; 
    endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();   ?>
```

In while loop you can display whater Title,Role as taxonomy, content etc